# UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit и его тонкости

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть такой кусок кода

```
<ItemsControl Name="icArrows" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeConstruct, Converter={StaticResource NodeToAllChildsConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="0" Height="0"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForTestingConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Почему-то `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` срабатывает безо всяких `UpdateSource()` при обновлении источника данных (`Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeConstruct`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `UpdateSourceTrigger` есть

> Описание измерения времени **обновлений источника** привязки.

То есть, для кода

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeConstruct,
                      Converter={StaticResource NodeToAllChildsConverter},
                      UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
```

`UpdateSourceTrigger` заведут движением информации из `ItemsSource` в `TreeConstruct.SelectedItem`, а не наоборот.

Comment: Точно. Это же триггер в другом направлении...